# fastboot in ubuntu sometimes works somtimes doesn't

Tags: android, adb

I'm having this really strange issues with fastboot in Ubuntu. In Windows 10 everything works fine.

Sometimes fastboot works and I can boot/flash recovery image I'm creating for my phone. But sometimes it just won't work. I get:

```
fastboot boot recovery.img
downloading 'boot.img'...
FAILED (command write failed (Success))
finished. total time: 0.000s
```

The USB cable is fine, it's new and on the phone screen in bootloader I see "Transfer Mode: USB connected."

Usually when fastboot refuses to work the screen on the phone becomes black for a few seconds then displays the bootloader screen for about 30 seconds, then becomes black again ... It almost seems as if it restarts the bootloader.

If I run `lsusb` I see my device:

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 22b8:2e80 Motorola PCS Fastboot kiev S
```

I tried all three USB ports on my laptop. I don't have other computers to test on. And since everything works fine in Windows, I doubt that there's something wrong with the USB ports.

The `adb` works fine all the time. Any ideas how should I proceed to diagnose this issue? It's really annoing to boot to Windows every time I modify my recovery in order to test it.

Thanks for your help!